# How do you map "dictionary tables" for various fields of your eloquent model

Tags: php, eloquent

In Eloquent you are taught to handle relationships between entities. Post <- Comment, or Comment <- User. In this situations you user hasMany, manyToMany or hasOne relationships.

How do you handle the situation when your related data is not an actual "entity".

For example, I might have a color_id column that maps values from a tables named "colors". I know it could be done with entities, but it feels a little bit overhead to build a eloquent model for color tables.

Bottom question, how do you map "dictionary tables" for various fields of your model.

Comment: Seems a bit of an overkill tbh. Not to mention it mostly depends on what you plan to use the data for or in what context in relation to other data.

Comment: These tables are different dictionary strings that map fields. Like country, county, etc

Comment: Ah, well in that case it may be a legitimate thing to do.